# What factors will lead to extremely high RMSE value in a regression model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression, evaluation

I was trying to build a regression model to predict movie box office. The dataset was acquired from Kaggle-TMDB 5000 Movie Dataset along with another dataset contains some social media related attributes.

After merging and cleaning, the final dataset consists of 183 observations and 53 features. Two categorical features, genre, and production_countries were expanded. For example, new columns like 'Action', 'Drama', 'Comedy'...etc. And the value is 1 if that movie belongs to that genre. Same as production_countries.

I used the dataset to build my regression model, but I encountered a problem. No matter I use train test split or cross-validation method or trying different regression model, the RMSE I got were insanely high.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_predict
X=movie.drop('Gross',axis=1)
y=movie['Gross']
print 'R2:',r2_score(y,cross_val_predict(RandomForestRegressor(),X,y,cv=10))
print 'RMSE:',np.sqrt(metrics.mean_squared_error(y,cross_val_predict(method,X,y,cv=10)))

output:
R2: 0.344831741145
RMSE: 76169019.1588
```

I don't know what factors are resulting in this kind of situation. Can anyone help me out here? Many thanks.

Comment: (1) I assume this question would be more appropriate at e.g. cross-validated.  (2) As the Wikipedia article on RMS deviation says, _...because the measure is dependent on the scale of the numbers used._  You can't conclude it's "too high" without claiming something about the scale.

Comment: Does it mean that if the target variable is a big number, it is normal for getting high RMSE value?

Comment: @c-ho:  I think so.  The RMSE hasn't been normalized, right?  Do a google search on "RMSI normalize".  See also the link in pablo reynoso's answer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are calculating properly the RMSE, I would check the R2 measure and try to do it manually just to be sure.

But I would try to review the concept more in detail, if we check the following reference: http://brenocon.com/rsquared_is_mse_rescaled.pdf

We can observe that

r2 = 1 - MSE(x,y) / VAR(y)

If MSE -> 0, consequently RMSE -> 0, and r2 -> 1.

But if RMSE -> +inf, MSE -> +inf and if MSE <= VAR(y) this will lead to r2 values lower Than 1 e.g. 0.2, 0.3, etc. So your results might place your analysis on the right track.